# What am I? - Vowels

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here is a What Am I riddle (that I made).

```
With an a, I'm a color
With an e, I'm a number
With an i, I'm an element
With an o, I'm a lot
With a u, I'm a container
```

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer

> The letters T and N

Explanation

> TAN = color, TEN = number, TIN = element, TON = a lot, TUN = [container](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tun) (a large cask, especially for wine)

Comment: Yay! Great job! I'll accept it as soon as I can. :)